# How do I create a foriegn key?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a foreign key "idUsers" from my users table. I want to be able to use it in my gallery table. Whenever I try I get the error:

> #1005 - Can't create table `useraccounts`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    idUsers int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY not null,
    uidUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    emailUsers  TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    pwdUsers  LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    about_me varchar (228) NOT Null,
    FOREIGN KEY (idUsers) REFERENCES users(idUsers)
);
```

I expect it to create the table but the actual output is the error:

> #1005 - Can't create table `useraccounts`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed").

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your uidUsers is referencing (or better yet, you want it to reference), primary key on the same table. In you gallery, you need to have field userId, which points to idUsers in users table. So, userId in table gallery is foreign key that is pointing to correct user. You probably want something like this (note the foreign key in gallery table that points to user)

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
  idUsers int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY not null, 
  emailUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL, 
  pwdUsers LONGTEXT NOT NULL, 
  about_me varchar (228) NOT Null
);

CREATE TABLE gallery (
  idGallery int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY not null, 
  idUser int(11) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES users(idUsers)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the foreign key references to the same column in the same table. Do you mean to create a primary key?

Foreign key references column(s) in another table.